# Container interface return abstract type iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, abstract

I must implement containers (list and vector) using templates, but I have a problem.
I have the following container template:

```
template <typename T>
class Container
{
public:
    class iterator
    {
        // ... pure virtual functions
    };
    // ... pure virtual functions
};

template <typename T>
class List : public Container<T>
{
public:
    class iterator : public Container<T>::iterator
    {
        // ... implemented functions
    }
    // ... implemented functions
};
```

But I don't know how to specify `begin` and `end` in `Container`, because I can't do

```
virtual iterator begin() = 0;
```

since iterator is an abstract class.

How can I, in `Container`, specify the return type of a function so that it refer to `List<T>::iterator` in `List` and `Vector<T>::iterator` in `Vector` ?
Or maybe a nested iterator for a container is a bad idea ?

I saw I could use smart pointers, but my compiler only supports C++98.

EDIT: So I went without inheritence, `vector` and `list` being totally independant.
But if you see any way to achieve what I asked above, feel free to answer.

Comment: I see no reason `iterator` should be in the `Container` class *at all*, and `begin()` and `end()` should return `typename T::iterator`, if I understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't see why iterator should be in T, T should not know it is in a container.

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you need a parent `Container` class? The standard library certainly doesn't work that way.

Comment: Because in the book I read (written by my teacher), he says there is a base container class, which vector and list inherit.

Comment: @BryanPeeters yeah, i totally spaced. I thought T was part of a crtp. it isn't (though this may utilize one in the end).

Comment: I can't see why you need inheritance here tbh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I, in Container, specify the return type of a function so that it refer to List::iterator in List and Vector::iterator in Vector ?

You can't.

> Or maybe a nested iterator for a container is a bad idea ?

It definitely it. I can't see why you need a `Container` base class or inheritance at all. The whole point of `iterator`s is to let algorithm, that work on them, be abstracted away from the type of the container (to a certain level). You don't need a base class to do that, and `std::vector` or any other STL container are not usually implemented this way.